# Сохранение файлов Cookies в ChromiumWebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, cefsharp

При установке значения `CefSettings.CachePath` я логично наблюдаю появление в указанной директории кучи файлов представляющих разные журналы логирования и кэш. Так вот, если установить `CefSettings.PersistSessionCookies` в `true`, файлы Cookies будут так же сохранятся в этой директории.

Меня интересует как сделать так, чтобы ничего кроме Cookies не сохранялось в процессе работы компонента. Ну, может быть, ещё GPUCache (слышал это полезно - почему?).

Comment: Полезно, - это когда работаешь с профилем отдельно.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня несколько учётных записей, вход в которые нужно запомнить, и я бы хотел выбирать нужные Cookies для каждой в отдельности. Мне кажется, если просто менять директории `CachePath`, то много разных ненужных сведений будет дублироваться.